# Rotating DNS servers specified by DHCP

Tags: linux, centos, dhcp, resolv.conf

I've got an OpenStack cluster running with about 200 CentOS instances and I've gotten a complaint from my hosting provider that the DNS traffic is getting to be too much for their servers. To address this I've set up a couple bind resolver instances and would like to push these out via DHCP, but I haven't been able to find a way to ensure that the resolv.conf directive `options rotate` gets either pushed out via dhcp, or can be set via some config file I assume would live in `/etc/sysconfig`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run back into this issue again, and after *MUCH* googling and raging I've found that the following will add `options rotate`, or literally anything else you want, to `/etc/resolv.conf` without locking down the file or otherwise breaking functionality:

Create put the following in the file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/rotate.sh`:

```
rotate_config() {
    echo "options rotate" >> /etc/resolv.conf
}

rotate_restore() {
    :
}
```

And then `chmod +x /etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/rotate.sh`.

Any executable file like `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/*.sh` will be picked up by dhclient/NetworkManager, and requires two functions, `*_config()` and `*_restore()` which will be run when the interface goes up/down respectively.

So `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/*.sh` needs `foo_config()` and `foo_restore()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `options rotate` setting is actually a client side setting, not something specified and distributed via the DHCP server.

You are going to need to set the config file. I tend to set it resolv.conf deployed by Puppet but I think it can also be set in sysconfig.

Comment: I wasn't able to track anything down on setting this via sysconfig, so I ended up just rolling it into a template in Chef and setting the nameservers via environment attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct that this is a client side config, however I am curious why you would want to do that ? what is your goal ? 
The reason is there might be other ways of achieving your goal,for example:

- you can use LVS ( linux virtual server ) to build a cluster of dns servers and present a single ip to all your servers.
- you can build a powerDNS recurser two node cluster with pacemaker and have this recurser use multiple name servers for its queries.

Comment: Both of those options are overly complex, and I've already gotten simple resolvers up and running.